# A friend of Pythagoras- What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I'm a friend of Pythagoras,

well more like a son of Pythagoras.

I am field,

not a baseball field.

But a field of mats.

My mum's name is atwo,

My dad's name is btwo,

Together, they made me- ctwo.

My leg is always shorter than my arms combined,

Sure, my leg can be a hypocrite,

Or something along those lines.

Well, anyway I better get going,

But I hope you'll get to know me,

Since i'm quite popular, really.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are

> A rectangle triangle (a triangle with a right angle)

*I'm a friend of Pythagoras,*
*well more like a son of Pythagoras.*

> Pythagoras is the author of the theorem named after him, applicable on rectangle triangles.

*I am field,*
*not a baseball field.*
*But a field of mats.*

> A triangle is a polygon, it has an area, a perimeter... It occupies space.

*My mum's name is atwo,*
*My dad's name is btwo,*
*Together, they made me- ctwo.*

> This refers to [Pythagora's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. The square of the length of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the square of the length of the two ther sides.

*My leg is always shorter than my arms combined,*
*Sure, my leg can be a hypocrite,*
*Or something along those lines.*

> The triangle's "leg", its hypotenuse, is always shorter than the combined lengths of the two other sides (arms). Hypotenuse also starts a bit like the word hypocrite.

*Well, anyway I better get going,*
*But I hope you'll get to know me,*
*Since i'm quite popular, really.*

> One would learn about this concept in school, and use it a lot throughout their scholarship.

Comment: Why didn't you ^vote the puzzle?  Maybe not yet.   I appreciate your solution.  This comment will self destruct.

Comment: Great job! I was looking "triangle" but "rectangle triangle" is also right.

Comment: I like they way you interpreted the word "mats" but I originally meant it to resemble "maths". So the sentence would read "But a field of maths" referring to trigonometry.